# gdb hangs after certain breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, gdb

I'm trying to debug a Fortran program (specifically, the PWscf program within the [QuantumESPRESSO](https://www.quantum-espresso.org) suite) with gdb, using VSCode with the C/C++ and Modern Fortran extensions. However, gdb hangs immediately after stopping at any breakpoint that is set after a particular line in the source. I've spent quite a bit of time investigating this issue, and I'm quite confident that it isn't related to VSCode or the extensions I'm using. Although PWscf contains MPI function calls, I'm building and running it serially. And the program works exactly as expected when running without the debugger attached, so I don't believe those MPI calls have anything to do with the issue I'm experiencing.

I'm starting the debugging process using the following VSCode debugging configuration:

```json
{
    "name": "(gdb) Debug pw.x with input file",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/pw.x",
    "args": ["-inp", "${workspaceFolder}/test_files/espresso.pwi"],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "Build pw.x"
}
```

The `Build pw.x` task is a VSCode task defined as follows:

```json
{
    "label": "Build pw.x",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "make pw",
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new",
    }
}
```

I'm using Debian 12, and VSCode is compiling using gfortran 12.2.0. This is the output of `gfortran -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 12.2.0-14' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-12/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-12 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-12-bTRWOB/gcc-12-12.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-12-bTRWOB/gcc-12-12.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
```

The software is built using autoconf and Make, and VSCode is simply running `make pw.x`, not specifying the compiler arguments directly.
However, after looking at the output of that `make pw.x` command, it appears that almost all the `.f90` files in the project are being compiled with the flags

```
-O3 -g -fallow-argument-mismatch -cpp -D__FFTW
```

and some other files in the project are usually included using the `-I` flag.

I'm using gdb version 13.1. This is the output of `gdb -v`:

```
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Execution begins in the [`pwscf.f90`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/PW/src/pwscf.f90?ref_type=heads) file. In my case, this calls a [`read_input_file`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/Modules/read_input.f90#L29) subroutine, which then calls an [`open_input_file`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blame/develop/Modules/open_close_input_file.f90#L62) function.
If I set a breakpoint at a point in execution at or before the call to `open_input_file` within `read_input_file`, everything works as expected: VSCode automatically opens the file containing the breakpoint, the line is highlighted yellow, and the variable explorer and call stack are displayed accurately in the "Run and Debug" sidebar. Additionally, I can run gdb commands in the debug panel.
This is shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwhAn.png), and the full debugger output, including that from the `bt` command I ran myself, is given below:

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=argc@entry=3, argv=0x7fffffffe309) at pwscf.f90:40
40    USE environment,          ONLY : environment_start
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0'. Symbols loaded.

Breakpoint 3, read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
48       IF ( ionode ) ierr = open_input_file( input_file_, xmlinput )
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
-exec bt
#0  read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
#1  0x0000555555565c4b in pwscf () at pwscf.f90:84
```

However, when gdb stops at any breakpoint executed after the `open_input_file` call shown in the previous image, even the very first line of the `open_input_file` function itself, gdb immediately appears to hang. VSCode doesn't open the file containing the breakpoint, no line is highlighted yellow, and the variable explorer doesn't display the correct values. Additionally, any gdb command run in the debug panel gives no result. This is shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeNsp.png), and the full debugger output is:

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=argc@entry=3, argv=0x7fffffffe309) at pwscf.f90:40
40    USE environment,          ONLY : environment_start
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0'. Symbols loaded.

Breakpoint 3, read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
48       IF ( ionode ) ierr = open_input_file( input_file_, xmlinput )
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
-exec bt
#0  read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
#1  0x0000555555565c4b in pwscf () at pwscf.f90:84

Breakpoint 2, open_close_input_file::open_input_file (input_file_=..., is_xml=.TRUE., _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at open_close_input_file.f90:93
93    IF ( PRESENT(input_file_) ) THEN
-exec bt
```

Note how the second `-exec bt` command above has no output, since gdb appears to hang immediately after hitting the breakpoint in line 93 of [`open_close_input_file`](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/Modules/open_close_input_file.f90?ref_type=heads).

I'm new to Fortran, but not to debugging. I have a decent amount of experience debugging Swift, Kotlin and Python code (although obviously none of these uses gdb) and I've never encountered an error like this before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: at the suggestion of @VladimirFГероямслава, I tried to run gdb directly, rather than using VSCode.
In this case, gdb didn't immediately hang after the problematic breakpoint, and I was able to run the `bt` command. But when I ran `info variables`, it crashed with a segfault.
I've included the (truncated) input and output below:

```
gdb bin/pw.x
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./bin/pw.x...
(gdb) break Modules/read_input.f90:48
Breakpoint 1 at 0x46f514: file read_input.f90, line 48.
(gdb) break Modules/open_close_input_file.f90:93
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5357b7: file open_close_input_file.f90, line 93.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jamestelzrow/q-e/bin/pw.x 
BFD: error: /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b5/94dc721d75112eb9f2aa7a2c0ae957f373d962.debug(.debug_info) is too large (0x15ef54 bytes)
warning: Can't read data for section '.debug_info' in file '/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b5/94dc721d75112eb9f2aa7a2c0ae957f373d962.debug'
warning: Section .debug_aranges in /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/b5/94dc721d75112eb9f2aa7a2c0ae957f373d962.debug entry at offset 0 debug_info_offset 0 does not exists, ignoring .debug_aranges.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

     Program PWSCF v.7.2 starts on  3Nov2023 at 22:12:29 

     This program is part of the open-source Quantum ESPRESSO suite
     for quantum simulation of materials; please cite
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 21 395502 (2009);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 29 465901 (2017);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Chem. Phys. 152 154105 (2020);
          URL http://www.quantum-espresso.org", 
     in publications or presentations arising from this work. More details at
     http://www.quantum-espresso.org/quote

     Serial version
     29762 MiB available memory on the printing compute node when the environment starts


Breakpoint 1, read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
48           IF ( ionode ) ierr = open_input_file( input_file_, xmlinput )
(gdb) bt
#0  read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
#1  0x0000555555565c4b in pwscf () at pwscf.f90:84
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, open_close_input_file::open_input_file (input_file_=..., is_xml=.TRUE., _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at open_close_input_file.f90:93
93        IF ( PRESENT(input_file_) ) THEN
(gdb) bt
#0  open_close_input_file::open_input_file (input_file_=..., is_xml=.TRUE., _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at open_close_input_file.f90:93
#1  0x00005555559c361e in read_input::read_input_file (prog=..., input_file_=..., _prog=_prog@entry=2, _input_file_=_input_file_@entry=256) at read_input.f90:48
#2  0x0000555555565c4b in pwscf () at pwscf.f90:84
(gdb) info variables
All defined variables:

File ../csu/abi-note.c:
71:     static const struct {
    Elf64_Nhdr nhdr;
    char name[4];
    int32_t desc[4];
} __abi_tag;

File ../dlfcn/dlerror.h:
83:     static struct dl_action_result * const dl_action_result_malloc_failed;

File ../login/utmp_file.c:
37:     static int file_fd;
39:     static off64_t file_offset;
38:     static _Bool file_writable;
42:     static struct utmp last_entry;

File ../nptl_db/db_info.c:
111:    const uint32_t _thread_db_const_thread_area;

File ../nptl_db/structs.def:
82:     const uint32_t _thread_db___nptl_initial_report_events[3];
80:     const uint32_t _thread_db___nptl_nthreads[3];
84:     const uint32_t _thread_db___pthread_keys[3];
98:     const uint32_t _thread_db_dtv_dtv[3];
116:    const uint32_t _thread_db_dtv_slotinfo_list_slotinfo[3];
95:     const uint32_t _thread_db_link_map_l_tls_modid[3];
96:     const uint32_t _thread_db_link_map_l_tls_offset[3];
66:     const uint32_t _thread_db_list_t_next[3];
67:     const uint32_t _thread_db_list_t_prev[3];
56:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_cancelhandling[3];
60:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_eventbuf[3];
61:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_eventbuf_eventmask[3];
62:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_eventbuf_eventmask_event_bits[3];
93:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_key_data_level2_data[3];
52:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_list[3];
63:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_nextevent[3];
53:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_report_events[3];
58:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_schedparam_sched_priority[3];
57:     const uint32_t _thread_db_pthread_schedpolicy[3];
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c

(I'm omitting this section of the output because it is a very long list of variables that I don't believe is relevant)

File qexsd.f90:
        integer(kind=8) _F.qexsd_module_MOD_clock_list;


Fatal signal: Segmentation fault
----- Backtrace -----
0x5645c7b4e40e ???
0x5645c7c57601 ???
0x5645c7c57776 ???
0x7feccb45afcf ???
        ./signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libc_sigaction.c:0
0x7feccb586618 __strlen_evex
        ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-evex.S:79
0x5645c7ba7083 ???
0x5645c7c6c62e ???
0x5645c7c6ca74 ???
0x5645c7ec2341 ???
0x5645c7e54df2 ???
0x5645c7e57795 ???
0x5645c7e5c2b3 ???
0x5645c7e5c440 ???
0x5645c7b80c94 ???
0x5645c7e8e287 ???
0x5645c7c57e1c ???
0x5645c7c593cf ???
0x5645c7c586d1 ???
0x7feccc62246c ???
0x5645c7c587fd ???
0x5645c7c5898f ???
0x5645c7c57d0c ???
0x5645c803f1d5 ???
0x5645c803fcb2 ???
0x5645c7d212f9 ???
0x5645c7d22f74 ???
0x5645c7ab1ca9 ???
0x7feccb4461c9 __libc_start_call_main
        ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
0x7feccb446284 __libc_start_main_impl
        ../csu/libc-start.c:360
0x5645c7ab8e30 ???
0xffffffffffffffff ???
---------------------
A fatal error internal to GDB has been detected, further
debugging is not possible.  GDB will now terminate.

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

Segmentation fault
```

Based on this output, I'm guessing that either the C/C++ or Modern Fortran plugin might run the `info variables` or some other command that causes a similar error, but does so quietly, and that's why gdb appears to hang in the debug console when run with VSCode.

I'll submit a bug report for the segfault to the gdb developers.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Which compiler version are you using? Which compiler flags? Which gdb version? Which OS (version)?

Comment: Please copy the debugger output from the console and paste it *as text*. This is very importsnt. You can also link to screenshots, but the text is the main thing. It is also way too small in those pictures for many screens. It is also not searcheable and not machine readable for visually impaired.

Comment: Also, what does gdb do the same when run from the command line?

Comment: Thank you for your replies @VladimirFГероямслава; I've edited my post to include the answers to your questions.